# sql server enforce constraint without a relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, relational-database

i'd like to implement a simple translation based on [this model](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/5489/querylan.png). I know that there are several ways to do it but I'd like to keep it simple.

my question is about constraint... obviously i can't create a FK relation, because I will save only the PN value in the order table, and the product PK is composite (id + language)

in order to mantain some kind of integrity (cascade delete or avoiding to delete an used product) what can I do? I'm thinking of triggers and/or business logic rules in my application code.

I'd like some opinions, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model doesn't make sense in terms of relations, you'd have to normalise to get somewhere near
e.g

Product (ProductID(K), Description)

ProductVersions(ProductVersionID (K),ProductID (FK), Language,(FK?))  with a unique compound key on ProductID and Language.

What are they ordering anyway a product or a product/Language?

Comment: the product is always the same, in this case "PN". I'm not interested in saving the language in the order. PN is all I need. the client will translate it using the user chosen language.

as you say I can create a reference adding another table, like you suggested. But it means adding a new translation table for every table that needs to be translated and it also means that all my queries will require at least one more join... it's more complicated.

i was looking for a simpler structure (if it's worth it), i'm still in the design process

Comment: I would pick Tony's advice. Don't fight the system. If you want constraints then normalise and take what RDBMS gives you out of the box. One extra join vs awkward model (like the one in screenshot) is an obvious choice for me.

Comment: Can't help you with that. If you don't take on the extra table so you can describe a relation to the database, then you can't have one, and you'll ahev to do all teh work to cope with potentially invalid data, forever, and ever. I know which choice I'd make, forever is a long time.

Comment: Think about it this way. You say the product is always the same, you write a system to implement that logic, then you send me teh product in Etruscan and tell me well its the same as the Messopotamian version. Am I going to agree? No! Get langauge on the order, save your self a lot of heartache. If translation is a process performed on a product to fulfil an order, then look at some sort of provisioning scheme. The compromises you seem to making will cost you big style in any future enhancement.